# Java 7 Try-With-Resources (AutoCloseable) Implementation

Tags: java, stream, try-catch, java-7

My question is more of *Why* type than *How*.

I know that in Java 7 the following works:

```
    try (
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);
    ) {
        .....................
      } catch (......) {
       ...............
      }
```

And the following gives a syntax error:

```
    FileInputStream in;
    FileOutputStream out;
    try (
            in = new FileInputStream(source);
            out = new FileOutputStream(target);
    ) {
        .....................
      } catch (......) {
       ...............
      }
```

I'm curious why is it so important for `Closable`/`Autoclosable` references to be **local** to the `try` block?  Is it just the logic that *if we didn't own it than it's dangerous to close*?

Comment: Mine seems like a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource?rq=1 . So the question was already asked but I do not believe it has been already answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a reference for this language design decision, but I think the issue is that allowing non-local variables to be autoclosed would be dangerous—that is, it would allow many unsafe coding styles. From [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> A resource declared in a ResourceSpecification is implicitly declared final (§4.12.4) if it is not explicitly declared final.

If the resources were not `final`, then inside the `try` block they might be reassigned, resulting in resource leaks. Since they are (implicitly or explicitly) `final`, the compiler would have to do a lot of extra work to ensure that the variables were [definitely unassigned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) at the point the `try` resource specification was entered. It would probably also require changes to the compiler semantics of `final`, since the variables really should not have a valid value after the `try` block exits; certainly not the value assigned to them in the `try` resource specification. The cleanest (perhaps only) thing to do is to make the variables go out of scope when the `try` block exits.