# Why do we have to do both declare and define resources in try-with-resource block?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

```
try(PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt")));) 
{}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above works fine. But when I do

```
PrintWriter f;
try(f = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt")));) 
{}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

It throws errors. Why is it so? I was testing this new feature and I was of the opinion I would take the 2nd method and after the `try-catch statement` would print the resource `PrintWriter f` - which should be null if try-with-resource statement works as expected. Why is the 2nd way not allowed?

Also how could I test it by method 1?

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) might help you, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource).

Comment: Read more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: What is the error?That might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Because `try-with-resources` actually adds the `finally` block for you in order to close the resources after usage, so they should not be usable anyway (after you leave your `try` block).

So this code

```
try(PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt")));) {

} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

actually translates into

```
PrintWriter f = null;
try {
    f = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt")));) 
     // now do something
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        f.close();
        catch(IOException ex) {}
     }
}
```

So this was the original purpose, save you from the bloated code and allow you to take care just about `try` block and leave the rest on JVM. Also see what Oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) has to say about this.

Comment: Your answer shows no reason why it would be forbidden to use an external variable for that. The JVM could still do all that stuff even with a variable from outside.

Comment: I suppose it's because you could bind that variable to something else inside `try` block, like `null` which would mean that JVM will probably not able to close the resouce properly.

Comment: Anyway, this has been already asnwered, I was trying to add something new to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

The code below, I believe, answers your question, with an unexpected result.

```
    PrintWriter t = null;
    try( PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter( "abc.txt" ) ) ) ) {
        f.println( "bar" );
        t = f;
    } catch( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( t );
    t.println( "foo" );
    t.close();
```

Output:

java.io.PrintWriter@1fc4bec

But, nothing is added to the file, as the writer was closed by the try.

Edit: If you want to play with TWR, write a class that implements AutoClosable, for example:

```
public class Door implements AutoCloseable {
    public Door() {
        System.out.println( "I'm opening" );
    }
    public void close() {
        System.out.println( "I'm closing" );
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        try( Door door = new Door() ) { }
    }

}
```

Output:

I'm opening

I'm closing

Answer (score 0):

Not perfectly sure, but doing some sophisticated guesses:

- The value of f after the catch block is potentially undefined. Therefore you would have to add all kinds of checks to verify whether the Object has been created, used, and/or is closed. But if you need all those checks, it would be simpler to not use that idiom in the first place.
- The JIT can happily optimize code with a block-local variable.
- The AutoClosure variable must not be set to a different variable during the try block, but can be afterwards. Maybe that's just too complicated for the JIT to check.