# The relation between "precise rethrow" and final Exception

Tags: java, exception, java-7

there are many question about java-7 feature "precise rethrow" and `final Exception ex`, i couldn't find clear answer for my question.

what is the relation between "precise rethrow"  and `final Exception` ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws OpenException, CloseException {
    boolean flag = true;
    try {
        if (flag){
            throw new OpenException();
        }
        else {
            throw new CloseException();
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    } 
}
```

is that obligatory to use `final` keyword if i want to use "precise rethrow" ?

```
catch (final Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

if it is not obligatory  can i reassign the `ex` reference to a new exception?

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e=new AnotherException();
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not required to declare the exception parameter (`e` in your examples) as `final` to get precise rethrow semantics.  You will also get precise rethrow if the parameter is [*effectively final*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473568).

In your second example, the parameter is NOT effectively final so you don't get precise rethrow semantics.

(This even applies if the exception you assign to `e` is assignment compatible with the original exception thrown in the `try` block.)

Reference: [JLS 11.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.2).