# How to find sum with forEach and lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The following snippet does not compile. How to find the `sum` using `forEach` as shown below?

```
private int Sum(ArrayList<Integer> inputs) {
    int sum = 0;

    inputs.stream().forEach(x -> sum += x);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @Pau The line `inputs.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();` is found in both accepted answers at the moment. The question in both cases is how to find the sum of a `List` of integers using `forEach`. Why is it not a duplicate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
private int Sum(ArrayList<Integer> inputs) {

  return inputs.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

}
```

EDIT :

The problem with using `for-each` is that it is a terminal operation, which means that it doesn't produce another intermediate stream for us to work on. The better approach would be to use `mapToInt` which produces an `IntStream` on which we can easily find the sum.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is just to provide a bit more context as to why your code doesn't work and therefore allowing you to decipher the problem if it were to happen in the future.

It seems like you're a .NET user which makes it completely understandable for one to expect the code you've written to work. As in .NET the equivalent would be:

```
private int Sum(List<int> inputs) {
        int sum = 0;
        inputs.ForEach(x => sum += x);
        return sum;
}
```

However, in java variables used in a lambda expression must be [final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473568/what-does-a-variable-being-effectively-final-mean) or [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456920/why-does-variables-in-lambdas-have-to-be-final-or-effectively-final), for that reason the statement `inputs.stream().forEach(x -> sum += x);` will not compile.

Nevertheless, simply because one would expect the aforementioned code to work in C# doesn't necessarily mean it should work in Java as there are different rules.

There are solutions available to find the sum of a set of numbers using the `forEach` method but it's not the idiomatic approach and so should be avoided unless necessary.

The idiomatic approach is as @Nicholas K has shown.

On another note:

- even in .NET the idiomatic approach would be `return inputs.Sum();`
  as opposed to using the `ForEach` extension method to sum the elements of a given list.
- whenever you seem to see yourself use `inputs.stream().forEach(...);` in java you should instead do `inputs.forEach(...)` as all lists have a `forEach` method.
- method names in Java should be camelCase as opposed to PascalCasing as in C#.