# NullPointerException error and cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, cardlayout

The NullPointerException only comes about when I click the 'next' button. 
I'm trying to get the frame to transition to another panel using cardlayout, but I have failed to do so.

Second question: How do I get my current panel to transition to the next panel (LoginPanel) in another class? I've already created an instance of it

```
public class InsuranceMain extends JFrame {

    private CardLayout cardPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton next;
    private JLabel label;

    public InsuranceMain() {

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardPanel);
        LoginPanel loginPanelA = new LoginPanel(this);
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cards.setLayout(cardLayout);

        next = new JButton("Next"); // Button
        label = new JLabel("Test");

        // Main frame settings
        setTitle("Travel Insurance Application");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonPanel.add(next);
        add(buttonPanel);

        card1.add(label);
        cards.add(card1, "card1");
        cards.add(loginPanelA, "loginPanelA");

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getSource() == next) {

                    cardLayout.show(cards, "loginPanelA");
            }}
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InsuranceMain test = new InsuranceMain();
    }
}
```

Here's my LoginPanel code. I apologize if it's very disorganized

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton loginB, registerB, clearB;
    private JTextField nricTextField, passwordTextField;
    private JLabel nric, password, loginTitle;
    private JPanel centerPanel, southPanel;

    private InsuranceMain main;

    public LoginPanel(InsuranceMain main){

        this.main = main;

        // JLabels
        loginTitle = new JLabel("Insurance Login", JLabel.CENTER);
        nric = new JLabel("NRIC: ");
        password = new JLabel("Password: ");

        // JTextField
        nricTextField = new JTextField("");
        passwordTextField = new JTextField("");

        // JButton
        loginB = new JButton("Login");
        loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getSource() == loginB) {

                    //cardLayout.show(cards, "card1");

            }}
        });
        registerB = new JButton("Register");
        clearB = new JButton("Clear");


        // North Panel
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // main panel's layout
        add(loginTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        // Center Panel
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        centerPanel.add(nric);
        centerPanel.add(nricTextField);
        centerPanel.add(password);
        centerPanel.add(passwordTextField);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

        // South Panel
        southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        southPanel.add(loginB);
        southPanel.add(registerB);
        southPanel.add(clearB);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code for loginPanel loginPanelA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NPE in the actionPerformed method can only be caused by cardLayout being null. So instead of

```
CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout(); // yields null
```

You should create the layout you need.

```
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
```

See also 
[Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

See also Erwin's comment.

Comment: In other words, the function of `getLayout()` is to get the layout of the panel? Pardon me for using the wrong terminologies

Comment: because the default layout for swing components is the null layout

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Your "non-final variable" link is no longer correct with Java version 1.8 and later, which introduces the concept of "effectively final". The OP may be using 1.8, on which the code will compile correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final

Comment: All is working now. Thank you guys. The problem now is the 'next' button yields no result although no error is displayed. Is there anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: @user3879549 add the code for LoginPanel

Comment: Alright, I've followed up to that already

Answer (score 1):

```
//change to 
    final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    final JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardPanel);
    cards.setLayout(cardLayout);
```

You have to declare the variables final so you can refer to them from an anonymus inner class
**new ActionListener() {}**

Also use the naming convention of java for naming classes => start with capital letter i.e InsuranceMain, LoginPanel