# Anonymous classes can access non-final outer objects in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Before java 8 an inner class could access outer objects only if they were declared final.
However now when I run example code (from below) on javaSE 1.8 there is no compilation error and program runs fine.

Why did they change that and how does It work now?

Example code from java 7 tutorial:

```
public class MOuter {
    private int m = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MOuter that = new MOuter();
        that.go((int) (Math.random() * 100), (int) (Math.random() * 100));
    }

    public void go(int x, final int y){
        int a = x + y;
        final int b = x - y;

        class MInner{
            public void method(){
                System.out.println("m is "+m);
                System.out.println("x is "+x); // supposedly illegal - 'x' not final
                System.out.println("y is: "+y);
                System.out.println("a is "+a); // supposedly illegal? - 'a' not final
            }
        }       
        MInner that = new MInner();
        that.method();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What JB said.  It's now "effectively final."  It was added to better support lambdas in Java 8 (which are like closures but a little different).

Comment: [Difference between final and effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java 7 the the concept of *effectively final* was introduced to support the ["more precise rethrow" feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), and its scope was expanded in Java 8 to cover local variables that are assigned only once, but not actually declared `final.` These can be captured and used in lambda bodies or inner classes just as if they were declared `final.`

This is covered in [section §4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html):

> Certain variables that are not declared `final` may instead be
>   considered *effectively final*.
>
> A local variable or a method, constructor, lambda, or exception
>   parameter is *effectively final* if it is not declared `final` but it
>   never occurs as the left hand operand of an assignment operator
>   ([§15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)) or as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or
>   decrement operator ([§15.14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14), [§15.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)).
>
> In addition, a local variable whose declaration lacks an initializer
>   is *effectively final* if all of the following are true:
>
> - It is not declared `final.`
> - Whenever it occurs as the left-hand operand of an assignment
>     operator, it is definitely unassigned and not definitely assigned
>     before the assignment; that is, it is definitely unassigned and not
>     definitely assigned after the right-hand operand of the assignment
>     ([§16 (Definite Assignment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)).
> - It never occurs as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or
>     decrement operator.
>
> If a variable is effectively final, adding the `final` modifier to its
>   declaration will not introduce any compile-time errors. Conversely, a
>   local variable or parameter that is declared `final` in a valid program
>   becomes effectively final if the `final` modifier is removed.

Comment: Actually, the notion of *effectively final* was added in Java 7, and used in the "more precise rethrow" feature.  Its scope was expanded in Java 8 to cover local variables captured by lambdas or inner classes.

Answer (score 3):

It's still the same rule, except the compiler doesn't force you to explicitely define the variable as `final` anymore. If it is *effectively final*, you can access it. If it's not (i.e. the compiler detects that the variable is reassigned), then it doesn't compile.