# Why was 'effectively final' introduced in Java 8?

Tags: java, final

The difference of a local variable being `final` or `effectively final` has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final). I do not really understand though, why it was introduced in Java 8. To me it seems like it just gives the programmer the freedom to leave out the `final` keyword, but treating the variable effectively as final. No change in logic, just a helper for the *'lazy'* programmer not to need to write `final`.

Isn't that even a step-back, since now a variable that is effectively final misses the keyword, not indicating it to the reader of the code. So is there a reason for Oracle to allow leaving out the final keyword here?

Comment: It was not introduced. What was introduced was the ability to access such variables from a Lambda expression. `Effectively final` is just a way to describe variables that don't actually change, and those existed in Java since it was created.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final

Comment: Less code saying more is not called "laziness", but "expressiveness". Thankfully, Java has begun to appreciate that virtue.

Comment: @Holger this question was not really a duplicate.  The question to which you redirected asked, _What_ is the difference.  This question asks _why?_

Comment: @james large: maybe you read more carefully. The question I linked is *exactly about WHY*. The question about the difference, which *others* have linked to, is another question.

Comment: @Holger Yes, it's almost an *uncanny* duplicate, and my answer a duplicate of yours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closures in Java (existing since version 1.1) can only close over `final` variables. With the helplessly verbose syntax of anonymous classes the few additional `final` modifiers were not such a big deal (although they did make for an occasional surprise when they jumped at you in parameter lists), but with the new concise lambda syntax, they are. They would also cause lambdas to less seamlessy blend into the fabric of the code. Especially consider the case of nested lambdas:

```
new TreeSet<Integer>((a, b) -> uncheckCall(() -> exceptionThrowingMethod(a, b)))
```

compared with

```
new TreeSet<Integer>((final Integer a, final Integer b) -> 
     uncheckCall(() -> exceptionThrowingMethod(a, b))
```