# Inner Local Classes in Java

Tags: java, local-class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b=1;
        final int c=2; 
        String s1[] = new String[]{"A","B","C"};

        class InnerMain{                                    
            int a=5;

            public void show(){ 
                System.out.println(s1[0]);
                System.out.println("A:" + a);
                System.out.println("B:" + b);
                System.out.println("C:" + c);
            }
        }

        InnerMain test =new InnerMain();
        test.show();
    }
}
```

The book I have studied says that a local class can use just `final` variables and references of method that local class is in. İn this example, I used variable `b` that isn't `final` or reference. It ran and I didn't get any error. How? Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between final and effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your book is probably outdated. Since Java 8 you can use [*effectively final*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) local variables.

If you tried to change `b` anywhere before, after, or in the local class definition, you'd get a compiler error.

Comment: thanks for your answer.And, how can ı follow news about java update?

Comment: @Furkan [This](https://www.oracle.com/java/index.html) is the official Oracle page.