# Use setter methods while iterating over collections using lambdas

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

This might seem a simple question, but I have been getting stuck on this little problem I have.

In java 7 you can iterate over your objects and set new values to its attribute.

```
for (int i = 0; i < continentLijst.size(); i++) {
        continentLijst.get(i).setContinentId(i);
}
```

Now I'm searching to do the same in a Java 8 lambda.
I thought something like:

```
 int i =0;

 continentLijst.stream().forEach(e -> {

        e.setContinentId(i++);
  });
```

Which obviously gives an error... 
As I said this might be a beginners mistake I'm making, but any help would be awesome!

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting? (Edit your original post)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't work because a variable used in a lambda expression must be [(effectively) final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) (and you are trying to update the value of `i`in the lambda expression).

You could hold a reference to a counter (such as an `AtomicInteger`)

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
continentLijst.forEach(c -> c.setContinentId(counter.getAndIncrement()));
```

or use an `IntStream` to generate a stream of corresponding indexes:

```
IntStream.range(0, continentLijst.size())
         .forEach(i -> continentLijst.get(i).setContinentId(i));
```

Comment: Allright I did not think of that! Thank you very mutch!