# Why lambda forces me to use single element array instead of final object?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have following class:

```
public class Item{
   private String name;
   //setter getter
}
```

And Collection of items. I would like to get name of last Item in Collection. To do that I simply iterate over all collection and use last. The problem is I dont know why it forces me to use one element String array.

Why do I have to use:

```
String[] lastName = {""};
items.forEach(item -> lastName[0] = item.getName());
System.out.println(lastname[0]);
```

instead of:

```
final String lastName;
items.forEach(item -> lastName = item.getName());
System.out.println(lastname);
```

Comment: A `Collection` has no order, if you want a specific element, you'll probably want to use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: `lastname`is `final` and you cannot assign a value more than once. So you cannot use it in a loop on the left side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: ... and http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html Chapter 7 - Variable capture

Comment: @Alexis C.: Please, use http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html there are almost two years of development between these versions.

Comment: @Holger I got this link in a blog post of 2013 :/ But you're right it's not very up-to-date.

Comment: Are you sure that “lambda forces you to use single element array”? I never experienced lambdas doing that to me…

Comment: Lambda no more "forces" you to use a single element array than unemployment "forces" you to rob a liquor store.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not make `lastName` a `String`, because a local variable that's used in a lambda (or anonymous inner class) must be (effectively) `final` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/1639625)), i.e. you can not overwrite it in each execution of the lambda in the `.forEach` loop. When using an array (or some other wrapper object), you do not assign a new value to that variable, but only change some aspect of it, thus it can be final.

Alternatively, you could use `reduce` to skip to the last item:

```
String lastName = items.stream().reduce((a, b) -> b).get().getName();
```

Or, as noted in comments, `skip` the first *n-1* elements and take the first after that:

```
String last = items.stream().skip(items.size() - 1).findFirst().get().getName();
```

Comment: This one is probably more efficient, as you don't need to process all the elements of the stream: `String lastName = collec.stream().skip(collec.size()-1).findFirst().get().getName()`

Answer (score 6):

`final` actually means that you must assign it once (and only once, as guaranteed by compile time analysis). For instance, the following code is invalid:

```
final String lastName;
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(new Item("only one element"));
for (Item item:items) lastName = item.getName();
```

In your second lambda expression, the consumer assigns to `lastName`, which has been declared as `final`:

```
final String lastName;
items.forEach(item -> lastName = item.getName());
```

Since variables referenced in a lambda expression must be [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) (i.e. such that the `final` keyword may be added to its definition), deleting the `final` keyword in the declaration of `lastName` doesn't help: here `lastName` is effectively final, and the consumer assigns to an effectively final variable.

```
String lastName; 
items.forEach(item -> lastName = item.getName());
```

On the other hand, in your first expression the *effectively final* variable is `lastName`, which is an array. Then you can do:

```
  String[] lastName = {""};
  items.forEach(item -> lastName[0] = item.getName());
```

Because here you are not assigning to the *effectively final* variable, but only modifying its elements (remember that what is constant is the reference, not its values), as it is also the case in the following example:

```
  final String[] lastName = new String[1];
  lastName[0]="foo";
```