# Compilation error using CollectionUtills of the new API of Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to iterate an array with some objects that contains a quantity and get the totalQuantity, but using the new API of Java 8 instead of the tipical for each loop.

This is the way I'm doing so far:

```
int totalQuantityOrdered=0;
    totalQuantityOrdered=CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(details)?details.stream().forEach(detail->totalQuantityOrdered+=detail.getOrderHeader().getQuantity()):totalQuantityOrdered;
```

However I'm getting a compilation error telling me that in order to use a lambda expression the variable totalQuantityOrdered has to be final. Then I think when a variable is final means that its value cannot be modified, so in that case how do I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thnk you in advance for your time.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28961578/1639625

Comment: This happens because in Lambda Expressions we cannot assign any value to some local variable declared outside it. So any variable used in a lambda is treated as final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much cleaner way to do this :

```
int totalQuantityOrdered = 
    details.stream()
           .mapToInt(detail -> detail.getOrderHeader().getQuantity())
           .sum();
```

This is assuming that `getOrderHeader().getQuantity()` returns an `int`.