# Why should I "Transform myVariable to final one element array"?

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables, scope

I'm trying to access the `h` variable in the inner class but an error keeps showing up "Cannot assign a value to final variable `h`". I tried quick-fix and it instructed me to "Transform h to final one element array".What does that mean?

```
int Update ()
{
    final int h;
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("PINCODE"))
            {
                h = sharedPreferences.getInt(key,0);

            }
        }
    });

    return h;
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think the listener has been called (to set `h`) before the program reaches `return h`? I don't see the logic in your code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why lambda forces me to use single element array instead of final object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961578/why-lambda-forces-me-to-use-single-element-array-instead-of-final-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the inner class you can't assign value to a local *variable* (itself) declared somewhere in the enclosing class, but you can change state (call methods, setters, ...) of the referenced object (if the variable points to some object and not to a primitive type). And array is object.

Check Java language specification - section about [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

The variable must be assigned as static in class MainActivity.

```
static int h;
```