# Referencing non-final variable: why does this code compile?

Tags: java, java-8, inner-classes

First off, I apologise if this is a duplicate question. I found many similar ones, but none that directly address my question.

In preparation for an upcoming exam, I am doing a past paper. It has a question that gives a code snippet. We have to state if it compiles, and if not, write the line at which the first compiler error occurs and explain it. This is the snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("hi");
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(50);

    jtf.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
            jtf.setText(evt.getLocationOnScreen().toString());
        }
    });

    f.add(jtf);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

I was expecting it not to compile as `jtf` is not `final`. I tested my theory by entering the code above in Eclipse, which flagged the expected error, but compiled and ran just fine. It was only after mousing over the `JTextField` that I got the expected error:

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Cannot refer to the non-final local variable jtf defined in an enclosing scope

I did a bit of searching, and discovered that Eclipse uses its own version of the Java compiler. So I remade the file outside of Eclipse and compiled/ran it via the command line. It compiled with no errors or warnings, and when mousing over the text field, displayed the desired `java.awt.Point[x=...,y=...]`.

My understanding of anonymous inner classes is that they can access:

- Fields of the enclosing class
- Methods of the enclosing class
- Local variables of the enclosing scope, provided they are `final`

So what am I missing? According to what I know, this code *should not work*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I guess you are compiling with Java 8. Here your `jtf` variable is effectively final, so it compiles fine. A variable is effectively final if its value is never changed after you initialized it.

See also [Local Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

> However, starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local
>   variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or
>   effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never
>   changed after it is initialized is effectively final.

and

[Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope, and Declaring and Accessing Members of the Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing)

> Like local classes, anonymous classes can capture variables; they have
>   the same access to local variables of the enclosing scope:
>
> - An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
> - An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>     scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.
>
> [...]

If you tried with:

```
javac -source 1.7 MyFile.java
```

you'll have your expected error.

```
.java:13: error: local variable jtf is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                jtf.setText(evt.getLocationOnScreen().toString());
                ^
1 error
```

So the answer of the exam question is: it compiles only if you're using Java 8+.

Answer (score 15):

Java 8 added the ability to access ["effectively final"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) variables. The `final` keyword is no longer required as long as a variable is never changed after it is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It may work in `Java8` as the stress is on `Effectively Final` which means once the value is assigned to `jtf` it should not be changed after wards. As per Java doc:

> A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is
>   initialized is effectively final.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your Eclipse IDE uses Java 7 compiler. To change this to Java 8 use Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Compiler compliance level.