# How to display a button and also display a random number when a user pressses the button?

Tags: java, swing

Hello I have been stuck on how to make a button display a random number.this is where I am right now. I cant figure out where the random number generator code would go. If I put it before the ActionListener if will just post right beside the button instead of appearing when the button is pressed. It keeps giving me the error message

**Error:** **Cannot refer to the non-final local variable num1 defined in an enclosing scope.**

Please refer the below code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        int num1;

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        num1 = generator.nextInt(101);
        System.out.println("the random number is:" +num1);

          JButton button1 = new JButton("Push Me!");

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           num1 = generator.nextInt(101);
        System.out.println("the random number is:" +num1);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setText` on the `JButton`. Also, don't forget to set a default close operation. You can't reference `num1` from the outer scope. I think you wanted something like

```
Random generator = new Random();
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

int num1 = generator.nextInt(101);
System.out.println("the random number is:" + num1);

JButton button1 = new JButton(String.format("Push Me! %d", num1));
frame.add(panel);
panel.add(button1);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int num1 = generator.nextInt(101);
        System.out.println("the random number is:" + num1);
        button1.setText(String.format("Push Me! %d", num1));
    }
});
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error message. i used what you have entered.

Comment: @sawg I tested my example in Java 8. The above is the main method, and it works here.

Answer (score 0):

The error relates to the fact that `num1` is declared as a local variable with the context of `main`, but which may be changed at some point in the future.

Have a look at [Referencing non-final variable: why does this code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141767/referencing-non-final-variable-why-does-this-code-compile) for more of an explanation

Instead, since it's not need until the `ActionListener` is called, just make it available to the `ActionListener` itself

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int num1 = generator.nextInt(101);
        System.out.println("the random number is:" + num1);
    }
});
```