# lambda expression and global variables

Tags: java, lambda

I just started working around lambda expression in Java 8. I'm bit confused about `effectively final`.

Local variable initialized once is `effectively final` but what about global variable, I can change value of global variable and use it in lambda expression. So what is the reason behind local variable should be `effectively final`. I couldn't find any articles or on javadoc about this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private String lastname = "Thakor";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main objMain = new Main();
        objMain.test();
    }

    public void test(){
        List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        listStrings.add("Vicky");
        listStrings.add("Thakor");

        String middlename = "V";
        //Local variable middlename defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
        /* middlename = "T";*/ 

        /**
         * In case of global variable, why lambda expression not throwing error...
         * Local variable middlename defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
         */
        lastname = "T"; 

        listStrings.stream()
                        .forEach(firstname ->{
                            System.out.println("Firstname: " + firstname);
                            System.out.println("Middle: " + middlename);
                            System.out.println("Lastname: " + lastname);
                            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                        });
    }
}
```

Output

```
Firstname: Vicky
Middle: V
Lastname: T
--------------------------------------
Firstname: Thakor
Middle: V
Lastname: T
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between final and effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Comment: @JordiCastilla, not really

Comment: @JordiCastilla I know the difference but I'm asking about global variable.

Comment: There are no global variables in Java. The instance variable is not in the (immediately) enclosing scope, it's just being used there. It's being accessed through a reference to the object itself.

Comment: @Vicky I can't recall the exact reason behind requiring local variables to be effectively final but I assume it has got something to do with threads using the local variables from the stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reference a "global" variable in a lambda, you're really capturing a reference to `this`, which is effectively final.

Consider the following snippet (untested):

```
class Main {

    class Box {
        int value;
    }

    void foo() {
        Box box = new Box();
        Runnable r = () -> box.value++;
    }
}
```

Even though you're changing the `box.value`, you're doing it through the `box` reference, which is effectively final. Similarly, you code is equivalent to

```
System.out.println("Lastname: " + this.lastname);
```

meaning you're accessing `lastname` through the `this` reference, which is effectively final.

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting your answer. I'm still confused.

Comment: @VickyThakor, which part are you stuck on? Do you understand the example snippet?

Comment: `accessing lastname through the this reference` Why it refer the variable as `effectively final` when accessing through reference? What makes it different from local variables? Frankly I don't understand the logic behind it. Can you explain it how java treat it from compiler level to run time.

Comment: @VickyThakor, I recently saw it put this way: Java closures close over *values*, not *variables*. `box` is a value. `this` is a value. `final` variables are effectively values. Allowing mutable variables to be referenced in a lambda would imply that the lambda captures the variable itself, not just its value.

Comment: Global variable you can update, but cannot do for Final declared variable