# What are the exact difference between Java 8 Lambda constructs and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, java-8

I have to convert Java 8 code to JavaScript (one way, once in a lifetime). To speed things up I want to automate as much as possible and use the test suite afterwards to fix all remaining issues.

I wonder what the difference between Java 8 lambdas and JavaScript (functions) are?

Any important incompatibilities?

Answer (score 12):

One important thing to note when comparing Java lambdas and JS functions is how the two treat scoping.

In Java, lambdas can only access effectively final variables and only captures those that are explicitly required. In JS, functions can access all variables in all the parent closures and thus captures everything.

A result of this is the possibility of memory leaks unless you know what you're doing. As an example:

```
IntSupplier getSupplier(MyMemoryHeavyClass heavy) {
    int x = heavy.hashCode();
    return () -> x;
}
```

This method will return a lambda that effectively only contains an int. No problems here. However, a naive translation to JavaScript...

```
function getSupplier(heavy) {
    var x = heavy.hashCode();
    return function() { return x; };
}
```

It may not be obvious at a glance, but this has a major problem. The function expression will capture EVERYTHING within the scope, including the `heavy` parameter (even though it's not referenced from within the returned function). As a result, it prevents `heavy` (which in this example requires a large amount of memory) from being garbage collected and will thus remain in memory for as long as the returned function exists.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, this information may be a bit out of date as modern engines appear to be more intelligent. V8, for instance, will apparently only capture whatever it deems necessary. However, it can still be tricked as all functions created in the same scope appear to share the same closure.

For instance, adding the line `(function y() { return heavy; });`, which would otherwise do pretty much nothing, will force `heavy` into the same closure as the `return x;` function uses, creating the leak.

While far-fetched in this specific example, it's far from unthinkable that similar problems may occur when naively translating Java methods containing multiple lambdas.

Comment: I'm not sure whether JS runtimes are *required* to keep `heavy` alive. Although, even if they optimize it out that would be implementation-specific behavior and not guaranteed by the spec.

Comment: Are you sure that JS runtimes do not optimize this? It would mean that it is very hard to implement JS functions properly without capturing the whole world. Is there a case in which a static analyzer cannot determine whether `heavy` is used by the anonymous function?

Comment: Feel free to find an engine that captures everything. Good luck.

Comment: It would appear that you're quite correct. I have amended my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

One major difference between JavaScript functions/arrow function expressions and Java 8 anonymous classes/lambdas is that the latter (Java) can't reassign captured variables and parameters as they are [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) *effectively final* in Java 8 (in previous Java versions all captured variables and parameters must be declared `final`). There are some workarounds to bypass this limitation:

- Use a custom `Mutable<T>` with `set` and `get` methods as a `Mutable<?>` instance might be passed as a captured variable or parameter.
- Use, let's say, `AtomicReference<T>` or some similar `Atomic***` methods (if I'm right, this approach cannot be used in GWT).
- Use a single element array as a value box, as array elements can be reassigned easily, let's say `Object[] o = {null}`. Despite this workaround seems to be more low-level and it requires careful reassignment/referencing via indexes, it may have the following advantages: 1) It deals with primitive types perfectly (say, `new int[1]` is definitely better than `Mutable<Integer>`). 2) An array can hold more than one value (let's say, your lambda expression might want to modify captured `r`, `g`, and `b` and the triple could be wrapped in `float[] rgb = new float[3]` where `rgb[0]` could be `r`). This workaround, if I'm right, is a suggested intention in IntelliJ IDEA.

So, if you have code with workarounds above in your Java code, you can try to get rid of those workarounds while porting to JavaScript. Let's say, the following Java code with primitive array box

```java
final float rgb[] = new float[3];
final Runnable whiteOut = () -> {
    rgb[0] = 255;
    rgb[1] = 255;
    rgb[2] = 255;
};
final Runnable blackOut = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        rgb[0] = 255;
        rgb[1] = 255;
        rgb[2] = 255;
    }
};
whiteOut.run();
blackOut.run();
```

can be easily translated to cleaner JavaScript (if you're fine with separate `r`, `g`, and `b`):

```
var r, g, b;
var whiteOut = () => { r = 255; g = 255; b = 255; }
var blackOut = function() { r = 0; g = 0; b = 0; }

whiteOut();
blackOut()
```