# Chaining lambda calls with stream and optional

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following code :

```
userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName())
                .map(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()));
```

The method findAllByClient return a `List<User>` type.
the map method returns a `Optional<Object>`
In my case it could (optional) return an `Optional<List<User>>`.
The idea I want to code is to use a stream on this optional list.
I'd like to chain my calls. Code in java 8 style is good looking and fewer lines of code.

I need to process this `List<User>` if it really exist (present). How can I chain my calls with java8 api : I wish to mix Optional and Stream.

Thanks.

EDIT :

I continue a bit further :

```
userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName())
.map(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()).stream().forEach(user-> 
{
    managedUserDTOs.add(new ManagedUserDTO(user));

}));
```

You've got the whole process. But this doesn't compile on instruction

```
managedUserDTOs.add(new ManagedUserDTO(user))
```

I want to fill the list and return it at final.

EDIT2 :

The whole wrapping method :

```
 /**
     * GET  /users -> get all users.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-liste",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.TC_ADMIN})
    public ResponseEntity<List<ManagedUserDTO>> getUserListe(Principal principal)
        throws URISyntaxException {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(managedUserDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I got the idea of your question, but:
`userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName())
                .flatMap(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()).stream()).foreach(<logic on each user>);`

Comment: ok I edit the original post

Comment: @FrancoisF I believe you are looking for, `userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName()) .map(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()).stream()‌​).map(user->ManagedUserDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't compile, eclipse underline all in red.

Comment: You have to show more of your code. Also, are you sure that your Eclipse is Java8-compatible? And that Java8 is enabled in the project settings?

Comment: I did an EDIT2. My eclipse is in java 8. I have a bunch of lines of code in java8 already

Comment: Have you read the error? Variables used in lambdas must be [effectively final or final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final). Are they?

Comment: @FrançoisF. Can you post the error. Also I am assuming `getUserWithAuthorityByLogin` returns `Optional<User>`. With that assumption, can you try `userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName()).map(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()).stream().map(ManagedUserDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList())).get();`

Comment: what does `getUserWithAuthorityByLogin` return?

Comment: Yes it returns  Optional<User> . 2 errors in your code : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Object> to <unknown> and userRepo‌​sitory cannot be resolved. Where as I inject like this :  @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

Comment: 1 error left : Optional<Object> to <unknown>

Comment: @FrançoisF. That should work. Looks like some encoding issue. I see some ? characters when I copy/paste it. Can you try the one in the answer. If you still see the same error, copy/paste it in notepad and save it and trying it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName()).map(user->userRepository.findAllByClient(user.getClient().getId()).stream().map(ManagedUserDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList())).get();
```

Same as the one in the comments section, but I think that has some encoding issues. I see `?` when I copy/pasted it. This should help.

Comment: It works ! That's quite more elegant code ! Thank you very much for your effort. You win the medal :)

Comment: @FrançoisF. Glad it helped as it is my first post of lambdas, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer but NOT IN JAVA8.
I would like the Java8 answer :

```
/**
     * GET  /users -> get all users.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-liste",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.TC_ADMIN})
    public ResponseEntity<List<ManagedUserDTO>> getUserListe(Principal principal)
        throws URISyntaxException {


        Optional<User> ouser = userService.getUserWithAuthorityByLogin(principal.getName());
        List<ManagedUserDTO> managedUserDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ouser.isPresent())
        {
            List<User> userListe = userRepository.findAllByClient(ouser.get().getClient().getId());
            for (User user : userListe)
            {
                managedUserDTOs.add(new ManagedUserDTO(user));
            }
        }

         return new ResponseEntity<>(managedUserDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```