# conditional sum in map.foreach java8

Tags: java, java-8

```
public Double getUnitsBefore(Date recordDate) {
    double eligibleUnits = 0;
    ageBucket.forEach((dateStr, units) -> {
        try {
            Date date = DFT.parse(dateStr);
            if (date.before(recordDate)) {
                //TODO These are eligible units for dividend.
                eligibleUnits = eligibleUnits + units.doubleValue();    //TODO 
            }

        } catch(ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    return eligibleUnits;
}
```

- As you know line `eligibleUnits = eligibleUnits + units.doubleValue();` does not compile in Java 8. How do i achieve this? I need to sum only when date is before record date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a stream instead:

```
return ageBucket.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> DFT.parse(e.getKey()).before(recordDate))
        .mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not compile because variable `eligibleUtins` is not [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final). If you want to use lambdas then restructure you code as flow of data (as in [@shmosel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266755/187261)) that does not change variables

Otherwise if you want to mutate variable then rewrite using a for loop

```
double eligibleUnits = 0;
for(Entry entry : ageBucket.entrySet(){
    String dateStr = entry.getKey();
    units = entry.getValue();
    // the rest of your code
}
return eligibleUnits;
```