# Increment an integer value that is outside a IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use an **IntStream** to increment an int value that is outside the stream.The point of this method is to find if there are chars on same position that are not equal. The n and word Strings are both same length.

When I try to increment the counter in the scope of forEach it shows me that it should be final or effectively final. Anyone could suggest a better way to do this or a way to increment this counter?

```
public boolean check(String n,String word){
    int counter=0;

    IntStream.range(0, n.length())
        .forEach(z->{

            if(n.charAt(z)!=word.charAt(z)){
            counter++;
            }
        });
    if(counter>1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;


}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `n.equals(word)`?

Comment: @Radiodef the words have same length but it should only return true if there is only 1 char that is different in the word on same position. Example hello and hallo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `forEach` to count occurrences, rather use the built in `count` method.

```
public boolean check(String n, String word){
       int counter = (int)IntStream.range(0, n.length())
                     .filter(z -> n.charAt(z) != word.charAt(z)).count();
       return counter <= 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd love an edit that breaks that on `.`s starting at `filter`.

Comment: sure thing. ^^.

Comment: I totally forgot about the filter option and the count method. This simplifies it a lot.

Answer (score 9):

There's a way to do what you want without needing to keep a `counter` variable:

```
public boolean check(String n, String word) {
    long count = IntStream.range(0, n.length())
        .filter(i -> n.charAt(i) != word.charAt(i))
        .limit(2) // short-circuit here!
        .count();
    return count <= 1;
}
```

This is like other answers. The only difference is that I'm using `limit(2)` to *short-circuit* the stream if we've already found 2 different characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `counter` as instance variable instead. For more, read [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44475074/4990642) about *effectively final*.

```
class Test {
    private int counter = 0;
    public boolean check(String n,String word){

        IntStream.range(0, n.length())
                .forEach(z->{
                    if(n.charAt(z) != word.charAt(z)) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                });
        return counter <= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work aka it doesn't give me that error anymore. Thank you.

Comment: I didnt -1 you. Your answer was correct and it helped me understand some stuff! @snr

Comment: I didn't -1 either but what would be the drawback of using `final AtomicInteger counter` instead of introducing a new instance variable that'll have to be maintained?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but maybe the downvoter didn't like your answer because it doesn't work with parallel streams. Besides, it has side-effects. Please take a look at the [`java.util.stream` package docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), where it is explained why side-effects shouldn't be used in behavioral parameters (i.e. your `forEach`'s `Consumer`). @ChiefTwoPencils The drawback is the side-effect.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: it doesn’t need a parallel stream to make this code break. Just call the method *again*…