# What is an open property? Why I can't make its setter to private?

Tags: spring, properties, kotlin, kotlin-allopen

What is the difference between a Property and Open Property in Kotlin? The code below complains on me declaring the setter *private* and Intellij says *private* setters are not allowed for **open** properties. What is an open property?

```
@RestController
open class ParameterController {

  @Autowired
  lateinit var parameterRepository: ParameterRepository
    private set //error


}
```

Why is the code above not valid but this code is?

```
open class ItemPrice{

    lateinit var type: String
        private set // ok

}
```

EDIT: I am using the spring-allopen plugin, and marking the class explicitly as open doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Your code has too much noise. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is an open property?

A **open** property that means its **getter**/**setter(?)** is not **final**. On the other hand, its *getter* & *setter* can be **override** by its subclasses.

In kotlin, everything is declared with **final** keyword except [interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#interfaces), [annotation class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html),  [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html), [enum class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html), [variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables), mutable property [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) and [parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#parameters), but the immutable [variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables) & [parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#parameters) are [effectivily-final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final).

Due to the `allopen` plugin will makes all of the properties & methods **opened** in the spring components.

However, a **open** property can't to makes a **private** setter, if the property is **opened**, for example:

```
//v--- allopen plugin will remove all `final` keyword, it is equivalent to `open`
open var value: String=""; private set
//                         ^--- ERROR:private set are not allowed
```

So you must make the property as **final** explicitly, for example:

```
//v--- makes it final explicitly by `final` keyword
final var value: String =""; private set
```

Comment: I am using the Spring-openall plugin, I'll edit my question to reflect that

Comment: Confirmed this is the correct answer. If I remove the Spring annotations the error does go away. The variables are now being declared as lateinit final var repo: ParameterRepository
    private set