# Accessing a private element through an inline created object in java

Tags: java, oop, java-8, inline, abstract-methods

I am new to java and trying some accessing methods and i encountered something that i do not understand. The code below working fine, prints 9 and not giving any compilation errors. 
I think this code should give a compilation error and number should be inaccessible from the test method, since new Human() is an instance of a totally different class. Can anybody explain me what is happening here ?

```
public class Test{      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 9;

        test("holla",new Human(){   
            @Override
            void test() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(number); // I think this line should not compile
            }               
        });    
    }

    private static void test(String a ,Human h){            
        h.test();           
    }    
}
```

Human Class

```
public abstract class Human {       
    abstract void test();    
}
```

Comment: What is `Human` and why do you think you couldn't access the variable `number` in a method where it was declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly valid (for java8 - prior to that, you would need thje `final` keyword when declaring `number`):

- you create an **anonymous inner** class that **extends** Human and provides the required implementation of the `test()` method.
- that method is using a variable from its enclosing "scope" - and the compiler is smart enough to detect that this variable is in fact a constant - as there no other subsequent assignments to it.

In order to "invalidate" your example: simply add an assignment

```
number = 42;
```

within the main method - after defining that anonymous inner class. Or use some version of java that is older than java8.

Keep in mind that anonymous inner classes are *closures*, and that the JVM is *copying* the values that are required "inside" from the outside. But when the outside value changes - which value should be copied. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) for further reading.

Answer (score 12):

You are correct before [java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

> In addition, a local class has access to local variables. However, a local class can only access local variables that are declared final. When a local class accesses a local variable or parameter of the enclosing block, it captures that variable or parameter.

Local variables should be `final` inorder to accessible inside anonymous classes.

Starting with Java 8, *effectively final* variables also allowed to access inside.

> However, starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.

try

```
int number = 9;
number=10;
```

now `number` is not at all *effectively final* and you get a compiler error saying *"Local variable number defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"*.

You might want to read [Difference between final and effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Comment: Thanks @Suresh! Makes sense.