# Why did Goetz not use volatile boolean for Listing 7.20 again?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, final, atomicboolean

Here is the code from listing 7.20 in Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice*:

```
public class CheckForMail {
    public boolean checkMail(Set<String> hosts, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException { 
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final AtomicBoolean hasNewMail = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        try { 
            for (final String host : hosts)     
                exec.execute(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                        if (checkMail(host)) hasNewMail.set(true);
                    }
                }); 
        } finally { 
            exec.shutdown();
            exec.awaitTermination(timeout, unit); 
        } 
        return hasNewMail.get();
    } 

    private boolean checkMail(String host) { // Check for mail return
        false;
    }
}
```

Referring this code, Goetz says that "The reason an AtomicBoolean is used instead of a volatile boolean is that in order to access the hasMail flag from the inner Runnable, it would have to be final, which would preclude modifying it" (p. 158).

Why does it **have** to be final? Couldn't you just make it a non-final boolean volatile?

Comment: Q: So who is "Goetz" and what are these numbers you're citing????  ANYWAY: here's an excellent article describing "a) What is Java `volatile`, and why would you ever need it?, and b) "How does `final` relate to `volatile`?  https://javax0.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/final-volatile/

Comment: Goetz is an author for a really great book Java concurrency in practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables can't be volatile. If you try to make that change, you'll see it's a compilation error.

Incidentally, as of Java 8, you no longer need to mark the variable as final; as long as it's [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) (that is, you don't set it after the first time), Java will accept it as if you'd marked it final.

Comment: Both your Johns answer got an upvote but accepted this due to faster reply time, but both answers are great.

Comment: Yshavit, if I may, since I cannot post for another 75minutes.

In listing 7.22 http://jcip.net/listings/WebCrawler.java TrackingExecutor exec is volatile, but I see no need for this. Sure the CrawlTask calls submitCrawlTask in a separate thread recursively, but I cannot see why visibility of TrackintExecutor exec is an issue if there is a happens before guarantee on the first time submitCrawlTask is called in a loop in the start method since we are first instantiating exec and the calling exec.execute

Answer (score 6):

> However why does it **have** to be final? Couldn't you just make it a non final boolean volatile?

`hasNewMail` needs to be accessed from the inner `Runnable`, as Goetz says.  That's an instance of an *inner class*.  In the most recent versions of Java, the variable being "effectively final" is a requirement for an inner class to access a local variable of a lexically enclosing method.  I think Goetz was writing at a time when the requirement was stronger: that the variable indeed be `final`.  The difference between "effectively final" and `final` doesn't really matter for this purpose, however, as either way, the variable cannot be modified.

Note, too, that the `AtomicBoolean` in Goetz's code is `final`.  It itself cannot be modified, but *the value stored within* can be, and this is how the program works.

Comment: So who the heck is this "Goetz" guy?  Why doesn't anybody give a first name, or a title?

Comment: @paulsm4, that would be Java language architect [Brian Goetz](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/briangoetzchief-188795.html).  The listing is from his book, [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/).

Comment: @Joihn Bollinger - Thank you :)

Comment: @paulsm4: he is also an [active Stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz).

Comment: @katiex7 - thank you for updating your post with the author citation: `code from listing 7.20 in Brian Goetz's Java Concurrency in Practice`.  It helps :)