# Testing the 4th object of an iterator - Java

Tags: java, list, iterator

Is it possible to assert the **only** value of the 4th object within an iterator?

I have seen examples of people looping over a list with an Iterator, but I don't want to get out the objects held in index `0` to `2`, but just that at index `3`...

I know that I could always do `.next().next().next()`, but that looks a little... silly. Is there any way in which I can do something like `.next(4)` to go direct?

Comment: No its not possible iterator is not created to allow direct access.

Comment: You can implement your own iterator, that has this feature. But in your case I would not use itearator.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I haven't used the Iterator a great deal, so the more I know :-)

Comment: Why not just `if(list.size()>3) { list.get(3); }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators don't work with index and they don't know at what index the last item appears. Their only purpose is to iterate through elements until the end is reached.

It means, if you want to work with the 4th element, you have to call [`Iterator::next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) four times. A situation there are only 3 or fewer elements in the iterator may happen, so you have to check against [`Iterator::hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--), otherwise when there is no more element and you call `next()` again, the [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) is thrown.

---

Alternatively, since Java-8 you can use the method [`Iterator::forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) which performs the given action for each of the remaining elements. Also, you need to use a trick with the array to avoid the [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) variable constraint within the lambda expression. Sadly, this method doesn't accept [`BiConsumer<T,U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) as an argument to consume not only the element but also its index - that's why this trick.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
int index[] = new int[]{0};

// Prints 4 and 8
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
iterator.forEachRemaining(i -> {
    if ((index[0]+1)%4 == 0) {
        // Here you work both with the element `i` and its index `index[0]`
        System.out.println(i);     
    }
    index[0]++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Guava [Iterators](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java)**

Guava has a common utility classes for this proposes. The exact answer in this terms will be:

In this example there is some risk to encounter [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) if `position` supplied is advance iterator beyond its *bounds*.

```
@Test
public void getNthElement() {
    List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Iterator<String> iterator = alphabet.iterator();

    int position = 3;
    String forthElement = Iterators.get(iterator, 3);

    assertEquals("d", forthElement);
}
```

The [Iterators](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java) has a convenient overload for `get(Iterator<T>, int)` method so you'll never get a [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

```
@Test
public void getNthElementWithDefaultValue() {
    List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Iterator<String> iterator = alphabet.iterator();
    int position = 10;
    final String actual = Iterators.get(iterator, position, "default");

    assertEquals("default", actual);
}
```

If its necessary to just skip or reach to specific position, but here comes the @Nikolas's mentioned case. Here you can easily get the `NoSuchElementException`

```
@Test
public void advance() {
    List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
    Iterator<String> iterator = alphabet.iterator();

    // will return the number of skipped elements
    int advance = Iterators.advance(iterator, 3);

    assertEquals(3, advance);
    assertEquals("d", iterator.next());
}

@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void advanceBeyond() {
    List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    Iterator<String> iterator = alphabet.iterator();

    int advance = Iterators.advance(iterator, 3);

    // throws the exception because we advanced iterator to end
    iterator.next();
}
```

**If you can't or don't want to depend on Guava**

Here is the very simple (educational) implementation to reach iterator's position.

```
public static <T> T get(Iterator<T> iterator, int pos) {
    if (pos < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position is negative!");
    }

    int i = 0;

    while (i++ < pos) {
        iterator.next();
    }

    return iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't restricted to the iterator, you can use Java 8 Streams to do something similar:

```
Object opt = collection.stream().skip(3).findFirst().orElse(null);
//opt will be null if there were 3 or fewer items in the collection
if(opt!=null) {}

//or to operate on the rest of the Stream
collection.stream().skip(3).forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) to concisely assert this:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = List.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).iterator();

assertThat(it).element(3).isEqualTo(8);
```