# Java8 lambda approach

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this piece of code that filters from a list of objects based on a set of String identifiers passed in and returns a map of string-id and objects. Something similar to follows:

```
class Foo {
    String id;
    String getId() {return id};
};

// Get map of id --> Foo objects whose string are in fooStr
Map<String,Foo> filterMethod (Set<String> fooStr) {
    List<Foo> fDefs; // list of Foo objects
    Map<String,Foo> fObjMap = new HashMap<String, Foo>(); // map of String to Foo objects


    for (Foo f : fDefs) {
        if (fooStr.contains(f.getId()))
            fObjMap.put(f.getId(),f);
    }
    return (fObjMap);
}
```

Is there a better Java8 way of doing this using filter or map? 
I could not figure it out and tried searching on stackoverflow but could not find any hints, so am posting as a question.

Any help is much appreciated.
~Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `filter` operator with the same predicate as above and then the `toMap` collector to build the map. Also notice that your iterative solution precludes any possibility of key conflict, hence, I have omitted that, too.

```
Map<String, Foo> idToFooMap = fDefs.stream()
    .filter(f -> fooStr.contains(f.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, f -> f));
```

Comment: This approach worked for me so accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When including items conditionally in the final output use `filter` and when going from stream to a map use `Collectors.toMap`. Here's what you end up with:

```
Map<String,Foo> filterMethod (final Set<String> fooStr) {
   List<Foo> fDefs; // list of Foo objects      
   return fDefs.stream()
        .filter(foo -> fooStr.contains(foo.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Function.identity()));
}
```

Comment: Please look at comment to first reply. It suffers from same compilation error.

Comment: The error message was "error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final". This means you have to make the variable "fooStr" final, I updated the answer.

Comment: @ggreiner there is nothing to do with the extra `final`. It's already `effectively final`

Comment: @ash **variables** used in lambda should be `final` or `effectively final`, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final

Answer (score 2):

Though *ggreiner* has already provided a working solution, when there are **duplicates** you'd better handle it including a `mergeFunction`.

Directly using [Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), one or another day you will encounter this following issue.

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), an **IllegalStateException** is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator) instead.

Based on the OP's solution, I think it would be better using

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*; // save some typing and make it cleaner;

fDefs.stream()
     .filter(foo -> fooStr.contains(foo.getId()))
     .collect(toMap(Foo::getId, foo -> foo, (oldFoo, newFoo) -> newFoo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Map<String,Foo> filterMethod (Set<String> fooStr) {
    List<Foo> fDefs; // get this list from somewhere
    Map<String, Foo> fObjMap = new HashMap<> (); 

    fDefs.stream()
        .filter(foo -> fooStr.contains(foo.getId()))
        .forEach(foo -> fObjMap.put(foo.getId(), foo))

    return fObjMap;
}
```

Comment: I get compilation error at the line: "error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final" at the fooStr.contains(foo.getId()))

Comment: The compilation error can be resolved by doing something like 
fDef.stream().map(foo -> foo.GetId()).filter(fooStr::contains))
But not sure how to get the foo object in forEach??