# Anonymous Class Accesing Local Variables

Tags: java, anonymous-class

If you look at my code below, you'll see I have declared int x = 0 in a method M(). I then declare an anonymous class within said method and declare int z = x. My question is that I though this would not be allowed, since x is defined in the encapsulating method which the anonymous class exists, and is not a constant. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Could someone please help clear my confusion?

```
public class SomeClass {
public void someMethod(Super pObj) {}
}

public class Super {
    public Super() {}
    public void aMethod() {}
}

public class SubClass extends Super {

    public void M() {
        SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

        int x = 0;

        someObject.someMethod(new Super() {

            int z = x;  

            @Override public void aMethod() {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Question. Didn't knew about effective final variables since java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` variable is **effectively final**, so can be used in an anonymous class (starting with Java SE 8).

For additional info you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Comment: Thank you for your response. So basically if I only declared x, and then tried to assign a value to it within the nested class, it would not be effectively final and throw an error? It makes sense, it's just a little strange haha.

Answer (score -1):

I have also used workaround witch wrapper final object. It this way, object is effectively final but you can change values in it.

final Counter counter = new Counter() ;
in anonymous class you can do:
counter. increaseValue() ;