# Problem while converting old-school if usage to Optional.ifPresent()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I am facing a problem while converting old-school if usage to `Optional.ifPresent`. Here is the previous version of the code.

```
State state = State.OK;
final Optional<Person> checkExistingPerson = checkIt();

if(checkExistingPerson.isPresent()) {
    Person person = checkExistingPerson.get();

    if("blah".equals(person.getName())) {
        state = State.DUPLICATE;
    } else {
        state = State.RESTORED;
    }

    return Member(person.getId(), state);
}

return Member(null, state);
```

And here is the `Optional.ifPresent` usage

```
State state = State.OK;
final Optional<Person> checkExistingPerson = checkIt();

checkExistingPerson.ifPresent(person -> {

    if("blah".equals(person.getName())) {
        state = State.DUPLICATE;
    } else {
        state = State.NEW;
    }

    return Member(person.getId(), state);
});

return Member(null, state);
```

And also, here is the screenshot what IntelliJ forces me to change it. 
[image]

What is the best approach to use `Optional` regarding to my problem? Thx all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. External variables inside lambdas need to be `final`.
2. [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) accepts a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) so it has no return value, therefore you can't use `return Member(person.getId(), state);` (also remember that you are inside a lambda, so `return` is not going to exit from your method, but from the lambda).

[`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) instead accepts a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) which has a return value, so you could use it instead of `ifPresent`.

This is how you could refactor your code, by moving `state` inside the lambda and by using `map` and `orElseGet`:

```
return checkExistingPerson.map(person -> {
    State state;

    if("blah".equals(person.getName())) {
        state = State.DUPLICATE;
    } else {
        state = State.NEW;
    }

    return Member(person.getId(), state);
})
.orElseGet(() -> Member(null, State.OK));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the value of a local variable from within a lambda expression. Besides, `ifPresent` can't return a value, as its return type is `void`.

Instead, you should use `Optional.map`, which transform the object wrapped by `Optional` if it's present:

```
return checkExistingPerson
    .map(person -> new Member(
            person.getId(), 
            "blah".equals(person.getName()) ? State.DUPLICATE : State.RESTORED))
    .orElse(new Member(null, State.OK));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing local variables inside lambda expression then variables should be final or effectively final, which means they can't be modify [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final), you can also declare variables inside lambda expressions., and topic regarding question `ifPresent` will take `Consumer` as argument which has no return type, you use `map` which will take `Function` and parameter according to @Loris

Comment: This doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

In the inner method you can't refer to external variables if they are not defined as final, you can change your method like that:

```
final Optional<Person> checkExistingPerson = checkIt();

checkExistingPerson.ifPresent(person -> {
    State state;
    if("blah".equals(person.getName())) {
        state = State.DUPLICATE;
    } else {
        state = State.NEW;
    }

    return Member(person.getId(), state);
});

return Member(null, State.OK);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now, for the inner return it says `Unexpected return value`. What is the reason of this one?

Comment: This doesn't compile