# How to implement method reference as a predicate?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I am new to java8 and I was trying to understand this piece of code. This is the piece of code:

```
Stream.of("A", "B", "C").anyMatch(someObj.getStringValue()::equalsIgnoreCase)
```

`someObj.getStringValue()` references some object and the `getStringValue()` returns some String value.

What is the equivalent predicate of the method reference being passed into `anyMatch(...)`?

My understanding was this would be equivalent to:

```
Predicate<String> p = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String t) {
        return someObject.getStringValue().equalsIgnoreCase(t);
    }
}
Stream.of("A", "B", "C").anyMatch(p)
```

With this I get the error "Local variable `someObject` defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final." Any explanation on this is appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938132/2928853) for a good explanation of what final and effectively final mean

Comment: it's a well-asked question, but I am afraid it's a duplicate

Comment: To understand a code piece, you don't necessarily need to rewrite it to a simpler construct. `someObj.getStringValue()::equalsIgnoreCase` is concise and expressive. I would check `someObj` on `null` and save `someObj.getStringValue()` to a varible, and use that varible like `thatVarible::equalsIgnoreCase `

Comment: Even when you were to explicitly declare the `Predicate`, you could remain with using lambda as `Predicate<String> p = t -> someObject.getStringValue().equalsIgnoreCase(t)`, which should take care of the effectively final implementation itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `someObj.getStringValue()` expression is evaluated outside, so equivalent code would be:

```
final String x = someObject.getStringValue();
Predicate<String> p = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String t) {
        return x.equalsIgnoreCase(t);
    }
}
Stream.of("A", "B", "C").anyMatch(p)
```

where the local variable `x` is "anonymous" too.

Because of this, `someObject` does not need to be *effectively final*.

You can verify this behavior for the *lambda expression* in a debugger, by putting a breakpoint inside `getStringValue()`. Even though the `test()` method is called 3 times (because the stream has 3 elements, and assuming no match), the `getStringValue()` method will only be called once.

Comment: Thanks for that example. Upon further read of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13 and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html I was able to understand in depth what was happening.