# Stream takeWhile for a sorted stream in the same pipeline

Tags: java, java-stream, java-9

I'm trying to filter a sorted stream using java9´s takeWhile to get objects from the beginning of the stream that share the same value for a field. I am unable to write the right predicate to do so. This can be done using two steps breaking the pipeline of the stream.

```
Stream.of(objA, objB, objC, objD, objE, objF, objG)
    .takeWhile(" get the value of objA´s field and take 
   as long as as other objects value for that field is the same as objA´s");
```

In two steps I could do something like

```
int x = Stream.of(objA, objB, objC, objD, objE, objF, objG).findFirst().get().getSomeValue();

Stream.of(objA, objB, objC, objD, objE, objF, objG).takeWhile(e -> e.getSomeValue() == x);
```

A simplified example could be

```
Stream.of(5,5,5,5,13,14,5,5,2,5,5,6)
.takeWhile(get the first four '5'´s)
```

Can this be done without the intermediate step using optional.get?

Comment: @ernest_k I get it passed as a parameter in a method. The code where the stream is built uses a library called streamex, which i have no experience with. the stream is not infinite even though the length of the stream is not known beforehand.

Comment: Is this the final step or do you need additional stream operations after `takeWhile`?

Comment: sorry still i don't get your question @nopens

Comment: @Glains No more complicated stuff after that. I need to collect those objects to a list, that would be the final step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (bit clumsy) workaround is to use a mutable holder object (because the reference must be [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)) that contains either `null` or the first value. We'll use `AtomicReference` in this example.

```
AtomicReference<MyClass> holder = new AtomicReference<>();

sortedStream.takeWhile(e -> holder.get() == null || holder.get().equals(e))
.map(e -> { holder.set(e); return e; })
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now this still contains an extra step, but as a `Stream` can only be processed once, the `findFirst()` approach won't work anyway. This also keeps setting the holder object even if it has been set, but that's just a minor annoyance rather than a problem.

As Holger pointed out, a better and more streamlined version would be

```
sortedStream.takeWhile(e -> holder.compareAndSet(null, e.getSomeValue()) || e.getSomeValue() == holder.get())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where with the first element `compareAndSet` assigns the value, returning true, and the subsequent elements are compared against the holder's value.

If you do use this approach, I recommend adding a comment pointing to this question/answer, or at least somehow try to explain what this code achieves, as it may not be immediately obvious to people reading the code.

Comment: Been trying to make a similar solution work with little 'clumsiness'... I think this will make it better: `.takeWhile(e -> null == holder.getAndUpdate(i -> i != null ? i : e.getSomeValue()) || e.getSomeValue() == holder.get())` - no need to repurpose `map`

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine. To be honest, I'm still trying to figure out what's going on. I'm definitely going to write notes and add the link. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ernest_k well, "better" is quite subjective. It certainly doesn't make it more readable, but this is the ugly part regardless of how it's done. I would probably go with `map()` just to try to keep it a *bit* more readable, but tomato / tomato, it's not going to be pretty in any case.

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks for your comment. I think with your addition I understand even better how you two solved this.

Comment: @ernest_k or just `.takeWhile(e -> holder.compareAndSet(null, e.getSomeValue()) || e.getSomeValue() == holder.get())`