# Java: Why could I access a local variable JPanel without final inside the anymous class?

Tags: java, swing

Suppose the code is:

```java
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        int a;
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // Correct
                a = 0; // Wrong, should be final
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It confuses me that why I can access the `JPanel` without a `final`?

Comment: @Eran thanks for the notice, and I have changed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

doesn't assign a value to a local variable (which is not allowed inside the anonymous class method). It mutates the state of the instance referenced by the `panel` variable, which is allowed.

The statement

```
a = 0;
```

which attempts to assign a new value to a local variable in not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Any references (or variables) accessed from a lambda (or an anonymous class) should be **either** *final* or *effectively final*, it depends on Java version you are dealing with:

- **prior** to Java 8 the final keyword is a must;
- **starting from** Java 8 and going further it's enough to have it initialized once, the reference is treated as a effectively final;

Both concept stand for you cannot re-assign values from a lambda.

Here are related threads on this issue:

- [difference between final and effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)
- [why only external final variables permitted in lambdas and anonynous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)