# Thread safe while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety

I have code like this:

```
while(true){
    var x = get();
    new Thread(()->parse(x)).start();
}
```

It dawned upon me that this may not be thread safe as the variable x may be (?) getting re-assigned.

However my function seems to be working fine.

Is this actually safe?

Comment: Should be, since Java does not have real closures; the value of `x` is copied to a synthetic final field of the lambda, so when the lambda is run in another thread, it reads it from that field, not the local scope of the `while` loop.

Comment: Wonderful stuff. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: In the nomenclature of a certain other programming language that shall not be named, the lambda _captures_ `x` _by value_.

Answer (score 3):

Variable x in your code should be *effectively final*, which means it can not be reassigned. See e.g. [this explanation](http://ilkinulas.github.io/programming/java/2016/03/27/effectively-final-java.html) or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final).

But the solution in general is not thread-safe, when x is an object and its fields can be accessed from outside. In such cases all changes to fields of x should be synchronized.