# Accumulate inside forEach Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How can I accumulate inside a forEach? this is my code:

```
public Double accumulate() {
        Double accum = 0d;

        numbers.stream().forEach(p-> {

            // if condition
                accum = accum + numbers.getAmount();
            // else
                accum = accum + numbers.getAmountWithInterest();
        });

        return accum;
    }
```

Maybe I should use map instead of forEach, I tried a couple of things but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: You can't obviously reassign `accum` in the lambda: it's effectively final https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final . Additionally, this is a wrong use of `forEach`. Try using `reduce` instead.

Comment: Also, a small note, Stream API is not a silver bullet, and you should not use it just because you can do it for a particular case (think first why). `forEach` is the most abused method, and you often can use a regular for-each statement, especially for this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not think it is a good idea to make side effect when using lambda. It is a bad way of mixing functional and imperative programming. You can do it easier by

```
numbers.stream().mapToInt(p-> {
    // if condition
        return numbers.getAmount();
    // else
        return numbers.getAmountWithInterest();
}).sum();
```

Comment: Should be `map`, not `mapToInt`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `mapToDouble` and `sum` instead of `forEach` with Java Streams:

```
@Test
public void sumOfDoubleWithStreams()
{
    List<Amount> numbers =
        Arrays.asList(new Amount(10.0, 0.0), new Amount(20.0, 0.05), new Amount(30.0, 0.1));
    double sum = numbers.stream()
        .mapToDouble(
            amount -> amount.hasInterest() ? amount.getAmountWithInterest() : amount.getAmount())
        .sum();
    Assert.assertEquals(64.0d, sum, 0.0d);
}
```

If you really want to use `forEach`, you need to have an object that can be mutated inside of the `forEach` call. You can use `AtomicDouble` here, or another class like `DoubleSummaryStatistics` or your own accumulating class.

```
@Test
public void sumOfDoubleWithForEach()
{
    List<Amount> numbers =
        Arrays.asList(new Amount(10.0, 0.0), new Amount(20.0, 0.05), new Amount(30.0, 0.1));
    AtomicDouble sum = new AtomicDouble();
    numbers.forEach(amount ->
        sum.addAndGet(amount.hasInterest() ? amount.getAmountWithInterest() : amount.getAmount()));
    Assert.assertEquals(64.0d, sum.get(), 0.0d);
}
```

If you are open to using a third-party library, you can use `sumOfDouble` on any container from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
@Test
public void sumOfDouble()
{
    MutableList<Amount> numbers = 
        Lists.mutable.with(new Amount(10.0, 0.0), new Amount(20.0, 0.05), new Amount(30.0, 0.1));
    double sum = numbers.sumOfDouble(
        amount -> amount.hasInterest() ? amount.getAmountWithInterest() : amount.getAmount());
    Assert.assertEquals(64.0d, sum, 0.0d);
}
```

I created an Amount class to hold the amount and interest rate:

```
public static final class Amount
{
    private final double amount;
    private final double interest;

    public Amount(double amount, double interest)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    public double getAmountWithInterest()
    {
        return this.amount * (1.0 + this.interest);
    }

    public boolean hasInterest()
    {
        return this.interest > 0.0d;
    }

    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.