# Why no instantiation outside try with resource

Tags: resources, try-catch

I want to write a method like this:  `public void print(Scanner scan)`,

and I want to use the try with resource to enclose scan in order to have it closed automatically.
However, I can't write this:  `try(scan)`

How come I am able to write:  `try(Scan scan = new Scanner())`, but I can't just put in the scan variable from my method parameter in order to get the benefit from try with resource?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is declaration required in Java's try-with-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource)