# Reference to AutoCloseable instance outside try block

Tags: java, autocloseable

For the convenience I would like to use `AutoCloseable` interface to do some stuff with the object which should be finalized before its **further** usage.

The only one problem is that `try-with-resources` block is thing in itself, I mean that in general for obtaining reference to my `AutoCloseable` instance, I have to do something like this:

```
    MyCloseable mc;
    try (MyCloseable m = mc = new MyCloseable()) {
        m.doSomeStuff();
    }
    System.out.println(mc.getValue1());
    System.out.println(mc.getValue2());
    // ... and so on
```

Here this construction:

```
MyCloseable mc;
try (MyCloseable m = mc = new MyCloseable()) {
```

looks somewhat messy. So my question is more about design problem. I doubt for what reason java architects didn't envisage such usage of `try-w-r` block as:

```
MyCloseable mc = new MyCloseable();
try (mc) { ... }
```

so may be I shoudln't use it as I described above? If it's a good practice to do that?

**EDIT** I was asked to explain why does my question differ from [Why is declaration required in Java's try-with-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource)

The explanation is very simple: I'm not asking **why?**, but: *If it's a good practice to do that?*

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13836486/1743880) is the same question. This will be possible in Java 9.

Comment: @Tunaki thanks, but I don't ask why it so, I ask, is it ok use it in such way from the design point of view

Comment: Ah, so you're asking if it's a good practice to do that?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, sure. But in any case your link is very useful

Comment: @Tunaki But according to the fact that Java 9 will allow this, I guess that the answer will be **yes, it's ok** :)

Comment: I guess so :). I can't find any objective reference for this. The initial enhancement request is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068948) with the discussion [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-January/030787.html).

Answer (score 3):

The intent of [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) is to automatically perform cleanups when it is *no longer used*.

So it would violate the principle of least astonishment to use the object after the try-with-resources block.

Comment: I'm not agree cause of 2 reasons: 1) `java-9` will allow such usage; 2) `Stream` interface in `java-8` is also `AutoCloseable` but it is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tunaki, he gave me very useful link to the related question: [Why is declaration required in Java's try-with-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource)

I was doubted not about **why** this restriction exists, but I was thinking that my idea of usage is something bad from the design point of view.

But according to the fact that `Java-9` [will allow such usage as](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068948)

```
MyCloseable mc;
try (mc = new MyCloseable()) { ... }
```

what is exactly I'm looking for, so I think, the answer to my question will be: **YES, IT'S OK**