# PrintWriter object variable cannot resolve to type when used in try with resources

Tags: java, try-catch, printwriter

I'm trying to create a new PrintWriter object within a try with resources block as below, but it's giving me an error saying `outFile cannot be resolved to a type`:

```
public class DataSummary {

    PrintWriter outFile;

    public DataSummary(String filePath) {

        // Create new file to print report
        try (outFile = new PrintWriter(filePath)) {

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

A reason why I didn't want to declare the PrintWriter object within the try block is because I want to be able to reference the `outFile` object in other methods of my class.

It seems like I can't do it with try with resources, so I created it within a normal try/catch/finally block.

The text file is being created. However, when I try to write to file in another method, nothing seems to be printing in the text file, `test.txt`.

Why is this??

```
public class TestWrite {

  PrintWriter outFile;

  public TestWrite(String filePath) {

    // Create new file to print report
    try {
      outFile = new PrintWriter(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      outFile.close();
    }
  }

  public void generateReport() {
    outFile.print("Hello world");
    outFile.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: That isn't **legal**. `try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(filePath)) {`

Comment: You might want  to look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836486/why-is-declaration-required-in-javas-try-with-resource)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but what if I want to assign `outFile` as an instance variable?

Comment: @doctopus Then you can't use `try-with-resources`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I made an edit to my original post. For some reason even with normal try/catch, the file is being created, but I can't write to file still

Comment: Because you `close` it in the `finally` block of the constructor. **Don't** do that.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense why I can't write. But the problem is if I don't include that how can i make outFile close if an exception is thrown?

Comment: This is why `try-with-resources` was invented. What you are doing is called an *anti-pattern*.

Comment: thanks @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do everything in a constructor, I will demonstrate the preferred way to use a `try-with-resources` and invoke another method. Namely, pass the *closeable* resource to the other method. But I strongly recommend you make the opener of such resources responsible for closing them. Like,

```
public void writeToFile(String filePath) {
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(filePath)) {
        generateReport(outFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void generateReport(PrintWriter outFile) {
    outFile.print("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for explaining